# (Simple) max-width: 100% not working for img (on mobile), see code

Tags: html, css, image

This, the simplest of codes, doesn't work. Why will it not resize on mobile?

Cheers

I was thinking that it doesn't know what to relate the 100% to (because of the table I use to align it center both vertically and horizontally), still, I cannot get it to work.

(HTML)

```css
html,
body,
#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#wrapper td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table id="wrapper">
    <tr>
      <td><img src="logo.png" max-width="100%"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a table, this responsive css will work

```
/* full view of browser */
html, body {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
}
/* table full width and no overflow */
#wrapper {
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   border-spacing: 0;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
/* table datacell also full width */
#wrapper td {
   width: 100%;
   padding: 0;
   vertical-align: middle;
   text-align: center;
}
/* image keeps aspect ratio */
#wrapper img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it keeps the functionality in the browser (Chrome) with a centered image. But, the problem is still there on mobile device (iPhone X/Safari), where the image is way too big and not centered either. What could be the cause?
Edit: Some old code was in the way and it now functions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Give the image a max-width to make it smaller, for example `max-width: 280px;` (on smartphone less then 320px) and add then an auto margin like this `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```css
div {
  display:flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
}
div > img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.png">
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oskery/o93dcmar/)

Comment: An `</td>` is not correct at the end of an `<img>` Copy/paste bug?

Comment: I tried this and it didn't function. I removed the </td> of course. Also, caused the image not to be center aligned on web too.

Comment: Ops, yes I indeed accidentally included a ```</td>``` from copy/paste. What doesn't function @JohanKragbæk, it sure centers the imaged both horizontally/vertically. Have you tried to "Run code snipper"? Here is a JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oskery/o93dcmar/

Comment: The other code did the trick. This probably would have too, if I fiddled a little with it. Thanks for the effort.